# Control Table Column Width

Tags: tables, columns

I wish to control the width in a table characterized by different columns per rows. Here is an excerpt of my table.

```
\begin{table*}[]
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | c | c | r |}

\multicolumn{5}{l}{Hello World}   \\
Ciao & $\textbullet$ & Hello  & $\textbullet& Hola  \\

\multicolumn{5}{l}{Hello World}   \\
Ciao & $\textbullet$ & Hello  & $\textbullet& Hola  \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The width of *what* do you want to control?

Comment: The width of each column separately. In particular where it is written "Ciao", "Hello" and "Hola".

Comment: Well, you have the `p{some width}` column type. B.t.w., will all cells in columns 2 and 4 have a simple `\textbullet` and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, they only have a \textbullet. The final form of the table will be without separation lines between columns.

Comment: Type `$\bullet$` (math mode) or just   `\textbullet` (text mode) but not `$\textbullet$` and anyway, whenever you open a math mode, close it ! (note the `$\textbullet& ...)`  You should take a look to the `tabularx` and `tabulary` packages  documentation for control of the width of the table and `booktabs` about nice rules in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three possibilities: reducing the number of columns to 3 and inserting the bullets at the beginning of the last two columns (fixed width: 2.5 cm) with the `array` package. Or, always with three columns, and inserting the bullets as separators between columns. Or with five columns,automatically inserting a bullet in columns 2 and 4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{| l >{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}p{1.5cm}>{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}p{1.5cm}|}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & Hello & Hola \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & Hello & Hola \\
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{| l *{2}{>{\textbullet}c p{1cm}}|}
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & & Hello & & Hola \\
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & & Hello & & Hola \\
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{| l@{\makebox[3em]{\textbullet}}p{1cm}@{\makebox[3em]{\textbullet}}p{1cm}|}
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & Hello & Hola \\
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Hello World} \\
Ciao & Hello & Hola \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not exactly what i'm searching, since what i want to obtain is a series of elements separated by aligned  bullets, this is the reason why i use a column for the bullet, in fact, in this manner, i can align them easily.

Comment: But in my solution, the bullets *are* aligned. I've added two other solutions, see if one of them suits you.